# Como mostrar el valor de objeto Session con Razor en NETCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

estoy empleando objetos de Session[] para almacenar ciertos valores que deberán ser mostrados en una vista(en un proyecto Web de NetCore 2.1).La session la creo en el mismo controller,pero pretendo visualizar el mismo valor en otras vistas. intenté con la sig. pero no me acepta la sintaxis

```
@model NamespaceProyect.Model
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
<div> Encabezado @{var strprovedor=HttpContext.Session.GetString("nombreprovedor") as string ;
        }
<table><tr>..</tr></table>
</div>
```

habrá otra manera o falta alguna referencia?

Comment: Le sugiero revise este pequeño pero útil artículo: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/